# Javascript Slider Shaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I took over the development of a website half finished, and on this site there are some sliders using jquery 1.3.2.  Suddenly, today, for the first time that I have seen, the sliders are shaking when they reach the end of the content.  Here is the site with the slider in question:

http://rareculture.com/index.php?dispatch=pages.view&page_id=18&artist=10

and here is the relevant code:

http://jsfiddle.net/yRV3P/

This was confirmed as shaking on another person's computer, both using Google Chrome.  In Firefox it is stuttering a bit, but not like in Chrome, where it's apt to give someone a seizure.  I don't see any other posts about shaky sliders here on stackoverflow, or elsewhere on the internet, but I guess it is possible that I am using the wrong search terms.  Has anyone else come across this?

Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't only happen when the slider reaches end of content... it would help if you'd post a jsfiddle reproducing the problem, your current fiddle seems to show no error in chrome..

Comment: Agreed, i cant find the issue in jsfiddle at all. Also, it could be worth upgrading jQuery if its possible, as i think its quite likely to be an issue with the javascript. + I look forward to seeing the answer!

Comment: After reading your comments about getting it to work in fiddle, I went back into the source code and found that there were two of the same javascript functions showing up for some odd reason.  I added it to the fiddle, and got the shaking.  Now to find out where the extra code is coming from.

Comment: Found the offending code, not sure why it was appearing twice, but nevertheless, it works now.  Thank you for your help.  I will leave the fiddle up for any else who have this issue.

Comment: you may post your solution as an answer to your question, otherwise it might stay open...

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout as it is more safe!

For me i could reproduce the bug. What I especielly recognized was that the slider is still going after I unhover, so when it comes to the end it appears as shaking.

when i need some work intervallish, i work as follows:

```
var active = false;
var timr = null;
var fn = function() {
     if (!active) return;
     doWork();
     timr = setTimeout(fn, 30)
}

var startWork = function() {
     clearTimeout(timr);
     active = true;
     fn();
}

var endWork = function() {
     active = false;
     clearTimeout(timr);
}
```

You can even skip the "active" stuff...